# How can I add text overlay to a video using php and ffmpeg?

Tags: php, video, ffmpeg

Here is the code and I couldn't find the error the. Basically it is not giving me any error just not doing it's work.

```
<?php

$video = $_FILES["video"]["tmp_name"];

$command = " ffmpeg -i " . $video;

$command .= " -vf drawtext=text='My text starting at 
640x360':x=640:y=360:fontsize=24:fontcolor=white";
$command .= " -c:a copy output2.mp4";

system($command);

echo "Overlay is complete";
?>
```

Comment: Maybe don't use the temporary file `$_FILES["video"]["tmp_name"]` but move_uploaded_file() first

Comment: Show the log from the ffmpeg process (assuming it actually executed).